# Kubernetes affinity and auto scaling behaviour

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster with a node pool and a given label on the node pool.
The cluster has auto scaling activated, with a minimum of 0 and a max of 2 nodes.

When I create a pod with an affinity matching the label, no node is created from the pool to schedule the pod on it.

If a machine of the pool is already up, the pod is scheduled on it as expected. Else, if no machine exists, the pod stays unschedulable.
What do I have to do to make sure a node is created when a pod with an affinity matching the node pool label comes up ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you down sized the node pool manually after the cluster creation, since GKE doesn't let you create the cluster if you set the size as 0 nodes.

Regarding the scaling up issue, it seems that was already reported in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/143972216). I would suggest you asking on that thread if there is any update or provide more information about your specific configuration.